# Node App - ReferenceError: uriUtil is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was workign on a Node App a few weeks ago which worked fine. I went to restart it today and its throwing this error

```
var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
              ^

ReferenceError: uriUtil is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\A\B\C\Web Applications\Donations1\routes\donations.js:14:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\A\B\C\Web Applications\Donations1\app.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:999:3
```

It relates to this line of code that connects to mongodb

```
  var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://AAA:BBB@ds053305.mongolab.com:12345/donations';
  var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
```

Comment: Where is `uriUtil` defined in your code?

Comment: Do you have anywhere in your code `var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri')` declared?

Comment: Theres no mention of uriUtil anyhere else but its there from default when you npm install mongoose it seems

Comment: Never rely on another module's dependencies or on some global variable. if you need a module, explicitly add it to your package.json and require it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace this line:

```
 var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
```

Which this line:

```
 var mongooseUri =require('mongodb-uri').formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
```

Don't worry to require same module more than once. Node always require only one time, and after that use the cache for loading the module.